# ftl convert multiline to single line for parsing it as json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have written ftl file where I am getting Product information.
Product info is coming like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
{
   "productName": "jjj",
   "productId": "10021",
   "description": "this is line
                   for testing
                   It is too long
                   so i am not
                   able to make 
                   it as a single
                   line
                   can anyone plase
                   help me
                   for this. i ma not able to pasre it as josn object",
  "price": "111",
  "priceTypeId": "1000"
}
```

when I am trying to parse this product info into JSON object with parseJSON() method. It's throwing an exception
now I want to make description from above content into a single line where new line should be replaced with \n\r so I can parse it by json object.
I tried one thing:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<#assign desc = desc?replace("(\r\n)+", "</p><p>",'r')>
```

it is making  desc content in a single line. but i want to show desc contents in multiline. what approach I can use? can anybody help me? finally i have to parse this desc  to json object. thanks in advance.

my ftl file:

```
<div id="jsonObj">
{
  <#if product?has_content  >
      <#if product.productName?if_exists?contains('&quot;')>
      <#--  condition to allow " in product name-->
      <#assign name=product.productName?replace('&quot;', '\\&quot;')/>
        "productName": "${name?if_exists}",
      <#else>
      "productName": "${product.productName?if_exists}",
      </#if>
      "productId": "${product.productId?if_exists}",
       <#--  condition to allow " and \ in product description-->
       <#if product.description?if_exists?contains('&quot;') || product.description?if_exists?contains('&#92;')>
         <#assign desc=product.description?if_exists>
         <#assign desc=desc?replace('&#92;', '&#92;&#92;')>
         <#assign desc=desc?replace('&quot;', '\\&quot;')>
          "description": "${desc?if_exists}",
        <#else>
        <#assign desc=product.description?if_exists>
         "description": "${desc?if_exists}",
        </#if>
      "price": "${product.sellingPrice?if_exists}",
      <#--  condition to allow " in part name-->
      <#if product.partNumber?if_exists?contains('&quot;')>
      <#assign pnumber=product.partNumber?replace('&quot;', '\\&quot;')/>
        "partNumber": "${pnumber?if_exists}",
      <#else>
      "partNumber": "${product.partNumber?if_exists}",
      </#if>
      "productCategoryId": "${product.productCategoryId?if_exists}",
      <#assign count=1/>
      <#list productAdjustmentInfo as productAdjustment>
       "itemTax${productAdjustment.adjustmentId?if_exists}Value": "${productAdjustment.value?if_exists}",
       "itemTax${productAdjustment.adjustmentId?if_exists}Name":"${productAdjustment.name?if_exists}",
       "itemTax${productAdjustment.adjustmentId?if_exists}TemplateAdjustmentId":"${productAdjustment.templateAdjustmentId?if_exists}",
        <#assign count=count+1/>
      </#list>
      "priceTypeId": "${product.priceTypeId?if_exists}"
      <#else>
       "description": "",
       "price": ""
  </#if>
 }
</div>
```

On Javascript, I am using below code to parsing

```
  var result = $(response.responseMessage + '#jsonObj').text();
  jsonObj = $.parseJSON(result);
```

Comment: If your question is about Javascript, please dont tag it with java!

Comment: Ok Gyro. I will take care of this next time.

Comment: where you get `.ftl` file? it _FreeMaker_? can you provide full template for this object?

Comment: possibly you need use [json_string](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_json_string) function or [j_string](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_j_string)

Comment: Yes Grundy this is FreeMarker.

Comment: I researched something like: encode the description before storing it in database and  decode it when we want to display.  It is working fine. Can I go through this approach or any other approach I can try?